# react-native push notification onNotification doesn't trigger

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-push

I am using zo0r [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library.

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "^0.45.1",
"react-native-push-notification": "^3.0.0"
```

This code runs every time I open an app:

```
PushNotification.configure({
    onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log('onNotification');
        ToastAndroid.show('onNotification', 3000);
    }
});
```

I send local push notification from background service:

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
    message: 'Hello World',
    smallIcon: 'ic_launcher'
});
```

The notification gets delivered. When I click it, `onNotification` method doesn't get called, then when I receive another notification, it actually gets called. It seems like it works only if app is in memory atm.

Am I doing something wrong?

I have opened a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/516) as well.

Comment: Did you get this working? I am experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my code I configured notifications outside `App` class - that was an issue. I just moved the configuration to App constructor and now it works just fine, onNotification gets called with no problem:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        PushNotification.configure({ ... });
    }
}
```

Latest `react-native-push-notification` lib version recommends the following: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#usage

Comment: hi, @andrei are you getting device token?

Comment: @Andrei I want to call onNotification after logged inside App, so I have created the main component where I called this inside constructor but this function not respond when sending test message from fcm? any idea?

Comment: @ArchanaSharma I think for the latest version, It has to be outside of all components so that it's called 100% before anything else. See Usage section: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#usage

Comment: I have used this outside the component life cycle(inside constructor of App.js main file), my question is every time when notication comes did this automatically receive this? Because here my App.js called once when app starts and after that console inside onNotification doesn't works when sending test message from fcm.

Comment: did you fix the issue I try the same but the PushNotification.localNotification is not trigger even I try to have button to onpress to tigger the function ?

Answer (score 4):

Its common issue, the issue occurs when using splash screen.
Edit the manifest like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
          <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. I have change code <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> to <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />

Answer (score 2):

It's specifically written to not put the configuration in the React life-cycle. Otherwise Android won't have the right behavior (I had so mush pain with this point !).
Here you have a nice tutorial:
https://product.farewell.io/visible-react-native-push-notifications-that-work-on-both-ios-and-android-5e90badb4a0f
It's bad explained, but the approach is perfect. Use a class to initialize and call the methods. Initialize the class in the top component as he suggests. It works good.
Complete the missing informations with this tutorial:
https://shift.infinite.red/react-native-node-js-and-push-notifications-e851b279a0cd
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I followed everything as per the document including React life cycle thing for android except below change where I was not  configuring proper intent filter action i.e.

```
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
```

Make below change and this should work

```
<service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Previously I was using this action because of that listener was not triggering

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
```