# React native Push Notification onNotification event not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

Been stuck for days on this one. So, I'm using this package for implementing local push notification:

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

I'm able to get local scheduled notification like this:

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        date: new Date(Date.now() + 30 * 1000), // in 30 secs

        /* Android Only Properties */
        //id: ''+this.lastId, // (optional) Valid unique 32 bit integer specified as string. default: Autogenerated Unique ID
        ticker: "My Notification Ticker", // (optional)
        autoCancel: true, // (optional) default: true
        largeIcon: "ic_launcher", // (optional) default: "ic_launcher"
        smallIcon: "ic_notification", // (optional) default: "ic_notification" with fallback for "ic_launcher"
        bigText: "My big text that will be shown when notification is expanded", // (optional) default: "message" prop
        subText: "This is a subText", // (optional) default: none
        color: "blue", // (optional) default: system default
        vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
        vibration: 300, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
        tag: "some_tag", // (optional) add tag to message
        group: "group", // (optional) add group to message
        ongoing: false, // (optional) set whether this is an "ongoing" notification

        /* iOS only properties */
        alertAction: "view", // (optional) default: view
        category: null, // (optional) default: null
        userInfo: null, // (optional) default: null (object containing additional notification data)

        /* iOS and Android properties */
        title: "Scheduled Notification", // (optional)
        message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
        playSound: true, // (optional) default: true
        soundName: "default", // (optional) Sound to play when the notification is shown. Value of 'default' plays the default sound. It can be set to a custom sound such as 'android.resource://com.xyz/raw/my_sound'. It will look for the 'my_sound' audio file in 'res/raw' directory and play it. default: 'default' (default sound is played)
        actions: '["Yes", "No"]', // (Android only) See the doc for notification actions to know more
        foreground: false, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was received in foreground or not
        userInteraction: true, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was opened by the user from the notification area or not
        data: { type: "test" } // OBJECT: The push data
      });
```

I want to call a function when user clicks on the notification and when the app opens. To achieve the following I did this in my App.js:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    PushNotification.configure({
      // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
      },

      // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
      },

      // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
      // default: true
      popInitialNotification: true,

      /**
       * (optional) default: true
       * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
       * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
       */
      requestPermissions: true
    });
  }
```

But `onNotification` function doesn't get called.

I've gone through the following questions on SO but no luck.

[react-native push notification onNotification doesn't trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616252/react-native-push-notification-onnotification-doesnt-trigger)

[React Native Push Notification onNotification callback is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978190/react-native-push-notification-onnotification-callback-is-inconsistent)

[Android onNotification never called in react-native-push-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238501/android-onnotification-never-called-in-react-native-push-notification)

I've also raised an [issue](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1145) on Github.

What can be the possible solution for this?

Comment: have you solve your issue?

Comment: @simo I am having this same issue, have you found anything?

Comment: maybe its related to this: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1952#issuecomment-502406940

Comment: Have you found any solution @3iL ?

Comment: @simo please check my answer

Comment: @KishanBharda, Please check my answer.

Comment: @Mandalina, Please checkmy answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for those asking for a solution, I did something like this in my app.js's `componentDidMount` method:

```
PushNotification.configure({
        // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
        onNotification: notification => {
          console.log(notification);

          if (notification.action === "Take") {
            //do something here
          } else if (notification.action === "Skip") {
            //do something here
          } else if (notification.action === "Snooze") {
            //do something here
          }
        },

        // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
        permissions: {
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true
        },

        // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
        // default: true
        popInitialNotification: true,

        /**
         * (optional) default: true
         * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
         * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
         */
        requestPermissions: true
      });
```